# How to load css from vendor folder using phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon, vendor

I already added the

```
$loader->registerFiles(
[ 
    BASE_PATH . "/vendor/autoload.php" 
]
);
```

in my loader.php file under config folder.

How do I use the libraries inside that folder like bootstrap, jquery and others.

I tried

```
 public function initialize(){
    parent::initialize();

    // Add import css

    $this->assets
        ->addCss("Bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css");
 }
```

in my IndexController file and still the css is not loading.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an asset with the asset manager, you still need to output the added CSS in your template like so:

```
{{ assets.outputCss() }}
```

Once you've done that, inspect the source and see what the rendered URL is.  Assuming you've installed Bootstrap into your public directory, you'll probably need to adjust the CSS path you're adding to: `public/vendor/Bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`.

Finally, if you're not modifying Bootstrap, you're much better off pulling it from a CDN.

Also, the loader is just for autoloading PHP classes - not CSS.

Comment: That's enlightening about the autoload.php. But how about if my vendor folder is same level with public folder. what would be the path then?

Thanks

Comment: There wouldn't be a path.  You can't have a file be accessible to the public (ie, JS and CSS), and not have it in the public/ folder.  That's what the 2 .htaccess files are for.  There's no problem with having 2 vendor/ folders - one in app/ for your server-side libraries and one in public/ for your client-side libraries.

Comment: Hi, how  to I load css files from my node_modules? node_modules is same level with my public. thanks.

Comment: If you have your .htaccess files set up like Phalcon suggests - you can't.  Only files in public/ will be accessible to the public.  You'll have to move node_modules/ into public/